# Single system image (clustering) solutions

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, lxc, cluster

Are there any Single System Image (clustering) solutions being actively developed? Kerrighed's last version targeted Linux 2.6.30 and the latest OpenSSI seems to target Linux 2.6.14.

Perhaps there's another solution that I'm not aware of though?

Is there any chance that Kerrighed would work on top of a later kernel, given it uses LXC? I see that 2.6.32 is still being supported by CentOS.

Answer (score 1):

You might look into [popcorn linux](http://popcornlinux.org/) as it is actively being maintained more than other clustering solutions such as OpenSSI.

Comment: Given its focus on heterogeneous architectures, it seems unlikely that they have/will implement e.g. process migration. It also looks superficially like it requires all kernels to have access to common memory, which won't be the case if the kernels are running on different physical machines.

Comment: It is an option that is actively being maintained so far that I know of. However the older OpenSSI *IS* still an option. At worse, one can begin building a prototype on one's own even if this is a LOT of work.

Comment: Came across another called `PelicanOS` that is alleged to be very quick to deploy but is stateless.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be an SSI solution.